# AngularJS search/find/filter div with specific anchored text value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Ok, so here's the deal: say you have list of `div`s with `a` tag, and **question** in that tag listed one by one as `display:block` on the forum. You click on the question - it takes you to the proper view or wahetever. 
Point is, You want to **filter** those questions by typing your *phrase* into the `form input` above. 
You want the **angular** filter to display only `div`s with `questions` that contain *phrase* you're typing, and leave only those in the view, hiding all others, like it does with simple lists we've all seen everywhere. 
It this possible? 
 How?

Comment: Showing some basic code of what you have attempted so far and are trying to accomplish would be a great start to deciphering this cryptic question you have posed...

Comment: The code is too long. Wouldn't bother. If it's too 'cryptic' for you - leave it.

Comment: If you aren't willing to bother with some basic code, why would anyone bother with attempting to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take the time to answer this even though you have put zero effort into showing your work so far. If the questions are being generated via ng-repeat, you can add a filter to it which will only show those that match the target value of your text input. Since there is no code example, I will create a basic one here.

Controller object:

```
$scope.produceItems= [ {id:"1", name:"Tomato"}, {id:"2", name:"Potato"}, {id:"3", name:"Lettuce"}, ... ];
```

HTML:

```
Search by name: <input type="text" ng-model="search.name">

<div ng-repeat="produce in produceItems | filter:search:true"> 
  <h1>{{produce.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Having the `ng-model="search"` will search all keys for the matching value and display in the ng-repeat accordingly.

Having the `ng-model="search.color"` will search only the color key for the match and display only those results that match.

There is ample documentation available on angular filters.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

I have updated the answer to more closely model what you described in your comment.

Comment: Ok, seems like you really want to help, despite my lazyness, so let me put it this way: - my array, considering your example, would be multiple divs, each of them has `h1`. I want to filter them according to text in `h1`. So say we have 3 `div`s, listed. One of them has `<h1> Tomatoes</h1>` other two: `<h1> Potatoes</h1>`. Now if I type **Tomatoes** I want angular to target `<h1>` and display this `div` with `<h1> Tomatoes</h1>`, and hide the other two.